# Find the modulus and argument of $e^{2+i}$ and $4e^{3+2i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function

The full question is to find the modulus, argument, real and imaginary parts of i) $e^{2+i}$ and ii) $4e^{3+2i}$.

I have tried tried to split $e^{2+i}$ into $e^{2}$ and $e^{i}$ and work from there and also use Euler's identity for $e^{i}$. However I am not entirely sure if this is the approach to take. It will be great if someone could help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modulus they are  $e^2$ and $4e^3$

because $e^{a+bi}=e^a(\cos{b}+i\sin{b})$ for all reals $a$ and $b$.

From here we obtain $Re\left(e^{a+bi}\right)=e^a\cos{b}$, $Im\left(e^{a+bi}\right)=e^a\sin{b}.$

The argument $\phi$ should be in $[0,2\pi)$.

Thus, $\phi=b+2\pi k$ for some  $k\in\mathbb Z$.

In our cases $\phi_1=1$ and $\phi_2=2$.

Comment: Hes asked real and imaginary part too Michael

Comment: @Isham In the starting problem I was added later. I fixed. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer really helped. I understand it now.

Comment: @Dblue You are welcome! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Well, in general when $\text{n}_{\space\text{m}}\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $\text{m}$ we get:

$$\text{n}_{\space1}\cdot\exp\left(\text{n}_{\space2}+\text{n}_{\space3}\cdot i\right)=\text{n}_{\space1}\cdot\exp\left(\text{n}_{\space2}\right)\cdot\exp\left(\text{n}_{\space3}\cdot i\right)\tag1$$

Now, using Euler's formula:

$$\exp\left(\text{n}_{\space3}\cdot i\right)=\cos\left(\text{n}_{\space3}\right)+\sin\left(\text{n}_{\space3}\right)\cdot i\tag2$$

So, we get:

$$\text{n}_{\space1}\cdot\exp\left(\text{n}_{\space2}+\text{n}_{\space3}\cdot i\right)=\text{n}_{\space1}\cdot\exp\left(\text{n}_{\space2}\right)\cdot\left(\cos\left(\text{n}_{\space3}\right)+\sin\left(\text{n}_{\space3}\right)\cdot i\right)\tag3$$

So:

- $$\Re\left(\text{n}_{\space1}\cdot\exp\left(\text{n}_{\space2}+\text{n}_{\space3}\cdot i\right)\right)=\text{n}_{\space1}\cdot\exp\left(\text{n}_{\space2}\right)\cdot\cos\left(\text{n}_{\space3}\right)\tag4$$
- $$\Im\left(\text{n}_{\space1}\cdot\exp\left(\text{n}_{\space2}+\text{n}_{\space3}\cdot i\right)\right)=\text{n}_{\space1}\cdot\exp\left(\text{n}_{\space2}\right)\cdot\sin\left(\text{n}_{\space3}\right)\tag5$$
- $$\left|\text{n}_{\space1}\cdot\exp\left(\text{n}_{\space2}+\text{n}_{\space3}\cdot i\right)\right|=\text{n}_{\space1}\cdot\exp\left(\text{n}_{\space2}\right)\tag6$$

Answer (score 1):

$\mathrm e^{2+i}=\mathrm e^2\,\mathrm e^i$, so
\begin{align}
\bigl|\mathrm e^{2+i}\bigr|&=\bigl|\mathrm e^2\bigr|\,\bigl|\mathrm e^i\bigr|=\mathrm e^2,& \arg\bigl(\mathrm e^{2+i}\bigr)&=\arg\bigl(\mathrm e^2\bigr)+\arg\bigl(\mathrm e^i\bigr)=0+1 \\
\operatorname{Re}\bigl(\mathrm e^{2+i}\bigr)&=\mathrm e^2\cos 1,&\operatorname{Im}\bigl(\mathrm e^{2+i}\bigr)&=\mathrm e^2\sin 1.
\end{align}
Similarly for $\;4\mathrm e^{3+2i}$.